# After Magento 2.4.3 install css and js not loaded. In url 'pub' missing

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento, localhost

After bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
In Magento frontend CSS and JS not loaded. In source code I found that

url shows href="https://localhost/love/static/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/en_GB/css/print.min.css" />
But it should be href="https://localhost/love/pub/static/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/en_GB/css/print.min.css" />

please any one help me !!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the Magento at that time you need to mention ***/pub*** in the base URL.

now you can mention it in ***core_config_data*** databse table, and then run the ***php bin/magento setup: upgrade*** command to solve the problem.

[See Screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/17619525?key=e015211e7776ee2e7e14c1c7f5d6b46f)